# Prompt asking user if they want to continue letting your app collect background location - How often does this occur?

Tags: ios, ios8, permissions, location

As you probally already know, one of the new features in iOS 8 is that Apple will occasionally ask the user something along the lines of:

> "Weather" has been using your location in the background. Do you want
>   to continue allowing this?

How often does Apple ask this and how do they determine when to ask? I can't find any documentation and my own testing has shown that it can range quite a bit. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each installed app will ask once when the update from ios7 to ios8 happens and the app is opened by the user.

Comment: In testing my own app, I have seen the above prompt appear several times over a period of a few weeks. The app was never reinstalled or anything like that, so I'm trying to understand how often users should expect to see this prompt. Does that make sense? Was that clear in the original question? Please let me know if not so I can edit it. Thanks!

Comment: Yea, it was clear.. I have read in the past that it would only show once, so that's weird..

Comment: @ori-k  i am also facing this problem. How did you fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with that alert.

When app request always authorization, OS will ask 
"Allow xxxApp to access your location even when you are not using the app?"

And a few weeks OS ask
"xxxApp has been using your location in the background. Do you want to continue allowing this?"
The second alert will show again every few weeks.

See some alert images at this web:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203033