# About iOS popup asking user to continue allowing the app to use location in the background

Tags: ios, background, permissions, location, authorization

I want to ask and to get better understand about the popup that iOS will occasionally ask the user like :

"Weather" has been using your location in the background. Do you want to continue allowing this ?

How often dose this occur and how do they determine when to ask ?
And is it possible to prevent this to show to the user ?

I can't find any documentation, the only explanation i can find is from the presentation from WWDC 2014 video "What's New in Core Location".

Thank,
Pat.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334052 though no answer there yet either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user has to agree to letting the app use their location.  Generally speaking the dev will only ask to use the users location when needed ie if they are searching for something on a map to compare to where they are currently.  Once the user has agreed to let the app use its location it isn't asked again.  From then on you check for updates in the users position.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tyler, I am asking about the popup that show again a few days later when the app is continue using the location in the background. At first launch the user allowed the app to use their location and because the app had functionality that need their location in the background even if there are not using the app, a lot of user said no to not allow the app to use their location again when the popup occur

Comment: that's why I want to know more about this popup, is it a one time thing or it will continue to ask the user to confirm again and again as long as the app is using location in the background  ? or Is there anyway we can prevent this.

Comment: It stores the allow or not allow under the locations settings of the phone so when the app asks the user it updates the setting and stays that way until the user changes it manually.  have a look Settings ->Privacy ->  Location Services  and you will see the apps that haver permission to use your location.